# How can we use long press to delete whole words, for custom keyboards in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

As we know, the original keyboard in iOS can delete whole words by holding down the delete button (⌫) for an extended period of time.
So how can we use the same functionality for custom keyboards in Swift, iOS 8?

*Note:*
I'm currently using `proxy.deleteBackward()` for deleting letters, and using:

```
var gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
gesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
button.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

when the button is pressed for a greater amount of time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would be able to do it through gesture recognizer.

The original keyboard behaviour is,

- When the button is pressed and kept pressed for initial X-time
  interval, it keeps deleting backward.
- When the button is kept
  pressed after the initial X-time interval, it starts deleting words
  instead of just characters.

After the button is pressed the first time, you should probably keep calling your delete function and keep noticing if 'X-time-interval' has elapsed. Pseudocode would be

```
var startTime: NSDate = NSDate()
var timer: NSTimer?
func deleteButtonPressed(deleteButton: UIButton) {
    startTime = NSDate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("delete"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func delete() {
    if !deleteButton.highlighted {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        return
    }

    if ((currentNSDate - startTime ) < "X-time-Interval") {
        // delete backward
    } else {
        /* figure out last space character in text and create NSRange
        then
        mytextView.text deleteCharactersInRange:theRange
        set new text */
    }
}
```

Comment: but I'm trying to build a custom keyboard Extension which can be use in other application (in whole system). How `mytextView.text deleteCharactersInRange:theRange` work then?

Comment: DeleteCharactersInRange is a function for text. So it should work. 
If your keyboard works universally it should know which textField/textView it's editing.