# Long press delete key of a custom keyboard in swift

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard. The delete key in the keyboard works fine for single tap. But it does not work for long press.I want to implement the long press on the delete key so that when the user holds down the delete button, the keyboard continuously deletes like in the standard ios keyboard. I referred to a couple of solutions on Stackoverflow, like- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234876/6077720,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25633313/6077720, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30711421/6077720

But none of it worked for me. I also tried this code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textDocument = self.textDocumentProxy

    var longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPress))
    self.deleteKeyPressed.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .Ended {
        print("Long Press")
        self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()

    }
}
```

But after writing this code my keyboard does not appear only. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: do you mean you are not able to show your keyboard?

Comment: @KetanParmar yes the keyboard does not display at all, after adding this code for delete button. Before that it worked properly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code below

```
var timer: NSTimer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   textDocument = self.textDocumentProxy

   var longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(KeyboardViewController.longPressHandler(_:)))

   eraseButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}

func longPressHandler(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .Began {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(KeyboardViewController.handleTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    } else if gesture.state == .Ended || gesture.state == .Cancelled {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}

func handleTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
    self.deleteText()
}
```

Comment: what timer do i use?

Comment: Use timer for the purpose of deleting text faster

Comment: i tired as you said but the keyboard is still not loading

Comment: without the long press implementation it works fine with just one tap on the delete button

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(KBViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    longPress.allowableMovement = 0.5
    row3B11.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

}

```
    func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
}
```

Comment: Some explanation what this code does and why it solves the problem would improve the answer quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok

please remove end gesture condition from your code, It will work fine

```
@objc func btnDeleteLongPress(gesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
}
```